# create a polynomial class, and when the class is called, it returns the polynomial equation in text form

Tags: python, python-3.x

Firstly, add_term method, adds one term to a Polynomial. The method takes two inputs - the first is the coefficient value, and the second is the exponent value. **str** method should return a string that represents that polynomial,  The string returned by this method should use the ‘^’ character to indicate exponentiation. The following example shows a Polynomial with both a negative and positive exponent:

Basic rules of polynomials should also apply, such as:
- If the exponent is 0, then 'x' is not printed (i.e., 2 rather than 2x^0)
- If the exponent is 1, then the exponent is not printed (i.e., 2x rather than 2x^1)
- Only terms with non-zero coefficients should be displayed
etc.

I can't really grasp my head around the problem, really need somewhere to make a start with. Please Thank you

```
p1 = Polynomial()
p1.add_term(123, 987654321)
p1.add_term(-9, -987654321)
print('p1 =', p1)
#Output is Below
123x^987654321 - 9x^-987654321
#Another Example can be seen below

p1 = Polynomial()
p1.add_term(1, 3)
p1.add_term(-4, 2)
p1.add_term(-100, 25)
p1.add_term(-66, 0) 
print('p1 =', p1)
#Output is below
p1 = -100x^25 + x^3 - 4x^2 - 66 + 6x^-7
```

Expected result can be seen in the code

Comment: What have you tried so far? If nothing, you can start here: 1) [Python classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and here: 2) [Sympy - Python library for symbolic mathematics](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Polynomial:
def __init__(self):
    self.terms = []

def add_term(self,coef,expo):
    if coef == 0:
        return
    self.terms.append((expo,coef))
    self.terms.sort(reverse = True)
def __str__(self):
    if self.terms == []:
        return str(0)
    out = ''
    pos= 0
    for i in range(len(self.terms)):
        x = self.terms[i]
        if i == 0 and x[1] < 0:
            out += '-'
        if x[0] == 0:
            out += str(abs(x[1]))
        #elif x[1] == -1:
        #out += '-x^' + str(x[1])
        elif abs(x[1]) == 1:
            out += 'x^' + str(x[0])
        elif x[0] == 1:
            out += str(abs(x[1]))+'x'
        else:
            out += str(abs(x[1])) + 'x^' + str(x[0])
        if(pos != len(self.terms)-1):
            if self.terms[i+1][1] > 0:
                out += ' + '
            else:
                out += ' - ' 
        pos+=1
    return out
```

This is the answer BOYS!!